# Using header when doing it from one script it refreshes data, from another it doesn't?

Tags: php, sql, refresh

I am using two scripts, one for deleting from SQL and one for adding to the database.

The issue I am having is that when running the add script it will refresh the page instantly showing the change. Yet, when running the delete script it doesn't refresh this instantly and seems that it caches the output?

If it does cache the output which it redirects to, why does one script show the addition and the other not show the deletion?

*Add Script*

```
// Set a URL for the user to be redirected to
$header_URL = "Location: ".WEBURL.DOCROOT."pages/parents-evening/{$_SESSION['status']}/";


// SQL statement using the variables from the user to insert into a specific table
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($values);";

// Check that the query was successful
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{
    // Success
    // Closes the database connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
    // Sets the redirect location
    header($header_URL);
    // Exits the script
    exit();
}
else
{
    // Fail
    // Closes the database connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
    // Sets the redirect location
    header($header_URL);
    // Exits the script
    exit();
}
```

*Delete Script*

```
// Set a URL for the user to be redirected to
$header_URL = "Location: ".WEBURL.DOCROOT."pages/parents-evening/{$_SESSION['status']}/";

// SQL statement to delete from the table provided where the ID is equal to either the POST or GET value
$sql = "DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE id = {$_POST['delete_id']}{$_GET['delete_id']}";

// Check the query was successful
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{
    // Success
    // Closes the database connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
    // Sets the redirect location
    header($header_URL);
    // Exits the script
    exit();
}
else
{
    // Fail
    // Closes the database connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
    // Sets the redirect location
    header($header_URL);
    // Exits the script
    exit();
}
```

Comment: "when I delete it doesn't"  It doesn't _what_? You go on to say that it _does_ eventually refresh, so what _isn't_ it doing?

Comment: @PatrickQ I have reworded my question. However, it 'refreshes' instantly when one script is ran, on the other it doesn't do this instantly.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have `{$_POST['delete_id']}{$_GET['delete_id']}`? I would expect only one of those. And you really _really_ should look into parameter binding.

Comment: Is the delete call being made via GET or POST? As Patrick says your syntax there is weird, I would only accept POST for an ajax call but if you really want both you can use $_REQUEST['delete_id'] as your variable

Comment: @PatrickQ That is next on my list of learning. I use both as I use both a form to get the ID and a URL parameter to get the ID on different pages;

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem is in this statement:

$sql = "DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE id = {$_POST['delete_id']}{$_GET['delete_id']}";

If you are getting `delete_id` from `POST` the query will be:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE id = ".$_POST['delete_id'];
```

If you are getting `delete_id` from `GET` the query will be:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE id = ".$_GET['delete_id'];
```

If there is only one record to be deleted (as seems `id` is primary key, so there will be only one record), i would recommend to use `limit 1`, as it will speed up the deletion process if you have huge data in your table.

Limit 1 will tell database to delete only one record so it will stop its execution when 1 record has been deleted.

Your final query will be:

For `POST`

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE id = ".$_POST['delete_id']." LIMIT 1";
```

For `GET`

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE id = ".$_GET['delete_id']." LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: My problem is not with the code executed as said above. The SQL statement runs successfully in its current state. The problem is that, when inserting data the page it redirects to shows the change immediately. When deleting data the page it directs to does not show the change immediately and takes considerable more time than I'd expect to show up on the page. This is shown as being completed immediately within the DBMS itself.